# How do I destroy all instances of Bootstrap Popover?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I have a single page app using Backbone, and whenever I over over something and then click the "back" button, the popover forever stays.

I want to destroy all instances of popover when a new instance is loaded.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Finding the popovers that are created through the data API is not difficult and has been covered in other answers like those of David Mulder and Amir Popovich. You just do:

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('hide');
```

Or you can use `destroy` if you need to or prefer to.

The challenge is to handle those popovers that are created **dynamically.**

#### Marking the Elements with Popovers

I would implement something like this. I'd override the default `popover` method and I'd try to perform this override as early as possible so that **everything** that needs a popover uses my override. What it does is just mark elements that use a popover with a class. Bootstrap does not mark them itself:

```
// Override popover so as to mark everything that uses a popover.
var old_popover = $.fn.popover;
function my_popover() {
  this.addClass('marked-as-having-a-popover');
  return old_popover.apply(this, arguments);
}
$.fn.popover = my_popover;
```

Then to clear everything before the unloading, I'd put in the code that detects the unloading the following:

```
$(".marked-as-having-a-popover").popover('hide');
```

Or it could use `destroy` rather than `hide` if testing shows that it works better for your use-case.

Now, the method above *will* work if the override happens early enough and you do not have a page where multiple jQueries are loaded. (Yep, this is possible.) I use something similar to deal with tooltips in one of my applications so I know the principle is sound. It so happens that in my app, all tooltips are created by my code so there is no risk of missing something.

#### Finding All Elements with Popovers, Even Unmarked

If you are in a situation where a popover can be created without being marked (I call this an "escapee"), then you need to query the whole DOM and find which elements have popovers. There is no shortcut here. You cannot rely on attributes like `data-content` because popovers can be created wholly dynamically (i.e. without any of the `data-` attributes). Also, all kinds of elements can get popovers, so you cannot reliably assume that only `button` elements will have a popover. The only surefire way to find everything that needs handling is to look at each element in the DOM and check whether it has a popover:

```
// Obviously this is quite expensive but in a situation where there *can* be escapees
// then you have to check all elements to see if they have a popover.
$("*").each(function () {
    // Bootstrap sets a data field with key `bs.popover` on elements that have a popover.
    // Note that there is no corresponding **HTML attribute** on the elements so we cannot
    // perform a search by attribute.
    var popover = $.data(this, "bs.popover");
    if (popover)
        $(this).popover('hide');
});
```

Again, `destroy` could be used rather than `hide`.

#### Proof of Concept

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc5baxb7/1/) that illustrates the entire thing:

- "Add a Dynamic Popover" simulates code that would add a popover when the override is in effect.
- "Add an Escapee" simulates code that would add a popover and somehow manage to use the original Bootstrap code.
- "Clear Marked" clears only the marked popovers.
- "Clear All" clears every single popover marked or not.

Comment: This answer is really good. If you work with fullcalendar.js and add popovers to the events you can actually just loop through all elements that have `.fc-event` and use *all* elements method to hide the popover. This way you don't have to loop all the elements in the document. You can actually use ``var popover = $.data(this, "bs.popover"); popover.hide(); `` to hide the popover

Comment: btw: $(".popover").popover("destroy") is an asynchrous call, that need some milliseconds (maybe this information is for someone important)

Answer (score 3):

try with this:

> $('YOUR_ELEMENT_SELECTOR').popover('dispose');

reference url: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple, just you have to call one function popover() with argument "destroy" to destroy the popover. It will destroy all popovers which is created by $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();

you can check [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) for more options and arguments of popover().

I suggest you to destroy popovers with having specific class name instead of using following code.

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('destroy');
```

The above code will destroy all popovers in the page. So instead of this, use class selector.

```
$(".YourClassName").popover('destroy');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have problems and need to remove all for sure:

```
$('.popover').remove();
```

will help (Popover automatic add this class, even for dynamicly created objects). It destroys all the popover DOM-Object incl. callbacks, etc.
But thats the rough way. Typically I displose all by popover class (clean way) and to be sure I do a hard clean up after. Works for me fine!

```
$('.popover').popover('dispose');
$('.popover').remove();
```

If you like to remove all execpt one, use a filter() with :not-Selector

```
$('.popover').filter(':not(#yourID)').popover('dispose');
$('.popover').filter(':not(#yourID)').remove();
```

popover adds also a id with a random number

```
#popoverxxxxx where xxxxx is a five digit number.
```

this helps sometimes to compare popovers. Of cause this could also be used to identify the popovers.

Answer (score 1):

Something generic like this (assuming you're using data-bindings) should do the trick:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide')
```

or the more extreme call

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('destroy')
```

though I doubt that would make sense often. Still to address the specific bug you're encountering you should create a minimal test case so that that bug itself can be addressed.

Oh and if you specifically want to check for open popovers you can use `.data("bs.popover").$tip.parent().length` (which is a bit of an hack), for example:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]:eq(0)').data("bs.popover").$tip.parent().length == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `hide` all popovers by using this:

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('hide');
```

You can `destroy` all popovers by using this:

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('destroy');
```

The difference between `hide` and `destory` is that when you `hide` a popover you **do not need** to **reactive** it, but when you **destroy** it you **do**.

Check out my [`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/6sw2ytsm/) and then:

- Click on all popovers and then click `hide`. After clicking `hide` you **can** click on the popovers again.
- Click on all popovers and then click `destroy`. After clicking `destroy` try clicking on the popovers again and see that **nothing will happen** since they are **destroyed**.
   In order to make them functional again, you will need to click on **reactive** and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Popovers must be initialized manually, so you know exactly what you have to destroy because you did initialize it.
You should just call the destroy function with the same selector.
Or maybe I am missing something ?